# In 1 Corinthians 1, who were Crispus and Gaius?

Tags: exegesis, 1-corinthians

1 Corinthians 1:14

> 14  I thank God that I baptized none of you, but **Crispus** and **Gaius**;

Comment: Two people from the church in Corinth. We don't know anything more, and we don't need to know anything more to understand Paul's point.

Comment: @curiousdannii - You are not quite right there...  Crispus was the inventor of new interesting ways to eat potatoes and Gaius was the inventor of ropes for helping put up tents.

Answer (score 2):

In the tradition of the Eastern Orthodox Church, Crispus was the ruler of the synagogue at Corinth.  He is understood to be the same Crispus that is mentioned in Acts 18:8:

> *And Crispus, the chief ruler of the synagogue, believed on the Lord with all his house; and many of the Corinthians hearing believed, and
>   were baptized.*

He is believed to have later become the bishop of the Greek Island of Aegina and, by some accounts, is understood to have been one of the Seventy Apostles.<sup>1</sup>

Gaius may have been the same Gaius who is mentioned in Romans 16:23:

> *Gaius mine host, and of the whole church, saluteth you. Erastus the chamberlain of the city saluteth you, and Quartus a brother.*

If so, he was, again according to Orthodox tradition, Bishop of Ephesus after Timothy.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sup>[Life of Apostle Crispus fo the Seventy](https://oca.org/saints/lives/2017/01/04/100042-apostle-crispus-of-the-seventy)</sup>
<sup>2</sup> <sup>[Life of Apostle Gaius of the Seventy](https://oca.org/saints/lives/2017/11/05/103182-apostle-gaius-of-the-seventy)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Who were Crispus and Gaius, as mentioned in 1 Corintians 1?

Crispus was a leader of the local synagogue.

> Crispus, the synagogue leader, and his entire household believed in the Lord; and many of the Corinthians who heard Paul believed and were baptized. - [Acts 18:8](https://biblehub.com/acts/18-8.htm)

As for Gaius, we are only sure that Paul stayed at his home when St. Paul wrote his Epistle to the Romans.

> 23 Gaius, who is host to me and to the whole church, greets you. Erastus, the city treasurer, and our brother Quartus, greet you. - [Romans 16:23](https://biblia.com/bible/romans/16/23)

According to Catholic tradition Crispus of Corinth is honoured as a martyr and saint.

> Convert, baptized by Saint Paul the Apostle. Leader of the synagogue in Corinth, Greece. First bishop of the island of Aegina. Martyr. - [Saint Crispus of Corinth](https://catholicsaints.info/saint-crispus-of-corinth/)

Catholic tradition also makes Gaius one of the seventy Disciples of Our Lord and a bishop of Ephesus.

> [Gaius of Ephesus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaius_of_Ephesus) is numbered among the Seventy Disciples. He was Bishop of Ephesus (Romans 16:23). The Catholic Church remembers St. Gaius on January 4 among the Seventy, and on November 5.
>
> **Possible reference in scripture**
>
> It has been suggested that this is the Gaius to whom the general Epistle 3 of St. John was addressed.

They are honoured together [(St. Crispus & Gaius)](https://www.catholic.org/saints/saint.php?saint_id=2769) by Catholicism on October 4th.